# Cannot install jenkins plugin. Getting an error occured unable to connect to jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
hosted on AWS. I can access the setup wizard; the problem I am having occurs after entering my admin password then proceeding to install the suggested plugins. I get an unable to connect to Jenkins message. Please, I need help on how to resolve this issue. I have spent hours trying to get this resolved by following suggested solutions but to no avail.

Thanks

[Unable to connect to Jenkins error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwmGk.png)

Maybe this helps. This is the error message I am getting from the log

```
    WARNING: null
        org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:384)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$3.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred (Invocable.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:270)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Same issue now with Jenkins 2.249.2 on AWS
`/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` is empty though.

Did you manage to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with the Jenkins plugin environment right now. I used to have a Jira issue number, but I don't know what it is now.

Comment: What kind of issue?